Gold atomic layer splitting during geometry optimization of MoS2 and gold heterostructure
The heterstructure was made by placing three layers of gold on top of a MoS2 monolayer with a (111) surface orientation of gold crystal,the (111) surfaces of metals are strained to match the optimized lattice constant of MoS2.During the ionic relaxation of the interface structures, the shape and size of the supercell is fixed with all the atoms allowd to be relaxed. After geometry optimization, one layer of gold atoms splits into two layers of gold atoms. The crystal structure and symmetry of gold have been completely changed!
The atomic configuration before relaxation is as follows:

The atomic configuration after relaxation is as follows:

The atomic configuration after relaxation with last gold layer fixed is as follows:

Has anyone encountered the same problem? Any suggestions will be appreciated!

You should check if the pseudopotentials you are using are good for Au.

I recently discovered a rather peculiar issue while re-optimizing this structure using VASP. Specifically, I performed geometric optimizations on two different configurations of the structure. The distinction lies in the fact that, in the second configuration, the MoS₂ layer is rotated by 90 degrees relative to the Au atomic layer—similar to the well-known twisted bilayer graphene. Upon comparing the relaxed structures of the first and second configurations, the first configuration exhibits greater structural relaxation of the Au surface compared to the second case and the second configuration exhibits almost no structural relaxation of the Au surface. Moreover, in the first example, the Au atomic layers show a tendency to split, resembling the behavior observed in the issue under discussion.
By the way, the lattice mismatch of the two heterostructures is almost equal.
The first atomic configuration after relaxation is as follows:

The second atomic configuration after relaxation is as follows:

